# How to access a List from the jsp to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, list, jsp

I am trying to transfer a list passed from the Controller (to the jsp), and pass the said list from the jsp to javascript.

The data on the list should replace the values of X (the date) and Y.

```
var data = {
    values:[
        { X: "8/7/12",  Y: 21 },
        { X: "8/8/12",  Y: 32 },
        { X: "8/9/12",  Y: 62 },
        { X: "8/10/12", Y: 8  },
        { X: "8/11/12", Y: 40 },
        { X: "8/12/12", Y: 12 },
        { X: "8/13/12", Y: 14 },
        { X: "8/14/12", Y: 72 },
        { X: "8/15/12", Y: 11 },
        { X: "8/16/12", Y: 98 },
    ]};
```

The list I wish to pass contains the following: 
1. the String version of LocalDate (Jodatime) - for the X axis 
2. the scores - for the y-axis

I have seen and tried a couple of solutions based on situations in various forums online, but none of them worked the way it was intended to. I also tried passing parallel arrays but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: If the list is available when rendering the HTML, just use it to write the initialization of an array in JS. Of course, you will not have access to the original list in the server (for that, you must look up for Ajax)

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation, I prefer to serialize the Java List object into a JSON string in the controller, and pass that string to the jsp.  Assuming your list contains instances of a class that looks like this,

```
public class MyObject {
    protected String X;
    protected int Y;

    // getters, setters, other methods and fields...
}
```

You can use libraries like [Gson](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.code.gson|gson|2.3|jar) or [Jackson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.4.2) to serialize the list in your controller.

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
// add some objects to the list...

String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
request.setAttribute("values", json);
```

In your jsp, the `values` request attribute is a string representing a complete javascript object in JSON.

```
var data = {
    values: ${values}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this from `JSP` to `Javascript`

```
var data = { values:[
        { X: <%=x[0]%>, Y: <%=y[0]%> },
        { X: <%=x[1]%>, Y: <%=y[1]%> },
        ...
    ]};
```

Note here I have use array of X and Y for values, you can use any data structure into jsp and later get it into javascript.

Alternatively If you are passing the data from `controller` to `jsp` you can use **JSTL** to iterate through the data and pass it to javascript.